# Xcode : AppDelegate.applescript : TextField

Tags: xcode, textfield, appdelegate

I created a new app using xcode / applescript. I'm doing like usual, inside AppDelegate.applescript, after property parent : class "NSObject"
I wrote : "property firstNameText : missing value"
But I can't link to "App Delegate"

[url1](https://postimg.org/image/cjuxe9b4t/)

[url2](https://postimg.org/image/6495ulu33/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing this backwards. You cannot just control-drag from the text field to the App Delegate. There are several ways to do it; I think the clearest and simplest is like this:

- In Interface Builder, in your *.xib*, select the App Delegate object on the left.
- On the right, switch to the Connections inspector.
- You will see your `firstNameText` property! Drag from the circle to the actual text field in the canvas or to the text field listing on the left.

[image]